# sign_in_as declaration in context clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

What does "sign_in_as :user" represent here?
Is that just a shortcut for a before block?
Just inherited a code base and I cant find docs for how it works.
Is there anyway to refactor it to a more documented format?

```
context 'when an User is logged in', sign_in_as: :user do

    context 'without the System Administrator role' do


        let :user do 
            create :user
        end




        it 'redirects to root' do
            action
            expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
        end

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntax to include helpers in your context. [Here](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-only-some-example-groups) is description and example of this feature.

So, check your `spec/spec_helper.rb` or `spec/rails_helper.rb` files. I think you can find declaration of `sign_in_as` inside of them.